# ShardMapManager.TryGetRangeShardMap wont retrieve the RangeShardMap

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-elastic-scale

I am trying to play around with the sample app provided by Microsoft [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Elastic-Scale-with-Azure-a80d8dc6).
This works fine for creating a new database and its shards etc. But it fails when i try to connect it to an existing DB with a single shard.

It has a class named `ShardManagementUtils` which provides the following method to retrieve `RangeShardMap<T>` from a sharded azure database:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new Range Shard Map with the specified name, or gets the Range Shard Map if it already exists.
    /// </summary>
    public static RangeShardMap<T> CreateOrGetRangeShardMap<T>(ShardMapManager shardMapManager, string shardMapName)
    {
        // Try to get a reference to the Shard Map.
        RangeShardMap<T> shardMap;
        bool shardMapExists = shardMapManager.TryGetRangeShardMap(shardMapName, out shardMap);

        if (shardMapExists)
        {
            ConsoleUtils.WriteInfo("Shard Map {0} already exists", shardMap.Name);
        }
        else
        {
            // The Shard Map does not exist, so create it
            shardMap = shardMapManager.CreateRangeShardMap<T>(shardMapName);
            ConsoleUtils.WriteInfo("Created Shard Map {0}", shardMap.Name);
        }

        return shardMap;
    }
```

My database has one shard in it and sharding data is kept in `Global Shard Map (GSM)`. When i call this method with by passing in correct `ShardMapManager` and `shardMapName`, following happens:

```
//this return FALSE, it should not
bool shardMapExists = shardMapManager.TryGetRangeShardMap(shardMapName, out shardMap);

//Then this line throw exception that map with this name already exists
shardMap = shardMapManager.CreateRangeShardMap<T>(shardMapName);
```

Exception being thrown is as follows:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.Azure.SqlDatabase.ElasticScale.ShardManagement.ShardManagementException' occurred in Microsoft.Azure.SqlDatabase.ElasticScale.Client.dll

Additional information: Shard map with name 'UserId' already exists in the store. Error occurred while executing stored procedure '__ShardManagement.spAddShardMapGlobal' for operation 'CreateRangeShardMap'.
```

So I checked the `__ShardManagement.ShardMapsGlobal` table and it contains shard map info in it. Then why would the first line not retrieve `RangShardMap` if it already exists?

What am I doing wrong.
Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a silly mistake from my side. I was about to `close` this question but thought to post my mistake here as it might be helpful to someone else.

The code to call this function was like this:

```
RangeShardMap<int> shardMap = ShardManagementUtils.CreateOrGetRangeShardMap<int>(shardMapManager, Configuration.ShardMapName);
```

Notice the `int` which tells the type of sharding key. In my case, UserId is `long` so `int` would not work.

Just changing the above line to following resolved the issue :)

```
RangeShardMap<long> shardMap = ShardManagementUtils.CreateOrGetRangeShardMap<long>(shardMapManager, Configuration.ShardMapName);
```

Comment: A quick update: We have published ShardManagement powershell module along with some sample scripts here: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Azure-SQL-DB-Elastic-731883db. This should help you in settings and querying the existing range/list mappings.

Comment: @SilviaDoomra Your link is dead